# Different usertypes with different access to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kinda newbie to php and may be is quite simple but I need some help on this task.

I have login login form for my Admin panel. I also have database and table users set and everything works fine so far. 
What I want to do is one SuperAdmin which I already have it. This superadmin have full access and no limits. He can see full datas in database.

Now I whant to have 3-4 more admins where every admin have access to his rows. For example now I have table `houses` with inserted `ids` 1,2,3,4. SuperAdmin has access to four id and he can see, edit, delete, update them.

Now here need another admin which will see only row with id=1. Another admin wich will see row with id=2 and so on. In other words each admin will have his records in database and must see only them.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
include('misc/db.inc.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password'] );

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".addSlashes($username)."' AND password='".addSlashes($password)."'");

$res = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($res == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['userobj'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    header('Location: main.php');
    exit;
} else {
echo 'error';
}
} else {
?>
```

In table `users` I've make new row `userType` where superadmin is with `1` and other admins are with `5`. 
How can I continue now? I guess I need some check for `usertype` while login. But after login how to give on each admin only the row of his access?

Comment: you'd need to store the permissions for every record somewhere, and check those permissions anytime you hit the database for any reason.

Comment: Like some separeted file which I will include in every file where some admin is loged. And from this file I will check what his usertype is?

Comment: no. you got the user's type when they logged in. but when you go to access some OTHER part of the system, you need to check right then and there if the user has access to that thing. how you go about that is up to you.

Comment: I see. But other admins now are with same `usertypes`. Do I need to put unique for each of them because if they are with same identifier they can reach each other records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store data in DB by privileges(permissions).

Examle: simple  DB struct:

```
UserTypes
-------------------------
|    id   |    title   |

|    1    | SuperAdmin |   
|    2    |    Admin   |    


Users
-----------------------------------------
|    id   |  type_id   |      title     |

|    1    |      1     |   Super        |
|    2    |      2     |   SimpleA_1    | 
|    3    |      2     |   SimpleA_2    | 
|    4    |      2     |   SimpleA_3    |  
|    5    |      2     |   SimpleA_3    |     


Table1 
-----------------------------------------------
|  id     |  user_id   |   field_1  ... field_N
|   1     |     1      |    xyz     ...   N
....

TableN
-----------------------------------------------
|  id     |  user_id   |   field_1  ... field_N
|   1     |     1      |    xyz     ...   N
```

**Each row of every table (if tables are not related by another indexes) must have field *user_id*.** After auth, you save user_id in session (for e.g.).Now, operations(select,update,delete,insert and others) with DB, you will do with abstract `... WHERE user_id=..`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand from where it came `user_id`. Is `user_id` related to `id` in `users` table?

Comment: @Jordan Vit I had wrote, for e.g., in session after authorization. First, you get user_id(implicitly user_type according my example DBstruct) by login/pass and store their in session.

Comment: This mean that I need to pass it also while I auth. Right?

Comment: @Jordan Vit yes, when you(or another user) logged (here was checking login/pass), you get user_id (save it in session). Now your can "divide" DB data by user_id (by permissions). SuperAdmin can see ALL data- we just omit "where user_id =...".

Comment: Well thank you. Now I have some starting points and will try to do it.

Comment: @Jordan Vit my answer is very schematic. See this http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/ or you can google , for e.g., like "php user role permissions".

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array($query);` instead of `mysqli_num_rows($query);`

by using `mysqli_fetch_array($query);` you can access `userType` field by executing the query and put check for `userType` while login.

**Code Here :**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".addSlashes($username)."' AND password='".addSlashes($password)."'");

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($res['userType'] == 1) {
    echo "Superadmin";
    exit;
} elseif ($res['userType'] == 5) {
echo "admin";
}
else
{
  echo "error";
}
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Yes, it's working. But when admin logs in I will redirect him to `admins.php` for example. And there what? How I will work only with datas from DB only for this admin?

Comment: They all have access to same database..tables, rows. Just different records from tables.

Comment: @JordanVit, you can also fetch data in `admins.php` according to `userType` by simply add `wHERE userType=1` clause in your query.